# Web-service which uses GPL software

Tags: licensing, web-development, web-applications, gpl, web-services

here's the problem.

I have developed an Azure-Based Web application which exploits some VMs. On top of these VMs I'm running a modified code which is licensed under the GPL license. Here's the flow:

[image]

Now, I would like to sell the access to the WEB-APP in the form of a private login to some customers.

1) Is there any limitations introduced by the software under the GPL license?

2) The idea is to sell only the access to the WEB-APP and hence the service I'm providing thru the VMs running the GPL software. Do I have to disclose the source code of the GPL software?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question which needs a copyright lawyer to answer accurately.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a lawyer but my understanding is that as long as you are not distributing the software, you don't need to do anything special.  You are free to use it for commercial uses.  This license was created before the concept of the cloud and the AGPL was created to address this loophole: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-affero-gpl.en.html